# Android Studio 0.8.1 can no longer install app. waiting for device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I upgraded to the latest android studio and as ever it breaks what was working fine before.

If I plug in my android device I can see debug in the debug monitor, it gets detected and i can select it as a device to deploy to, then I get

Waiting for device.
Target device: xxxxxxxxxxxx

and nothing else happens.. VERY frustrating. Anyone any ideas on how to resolve?

Here is the resolution:
The problem is the way i installed the newer version of Android Studio. Do not install it over your previous installation directory. Create a new directory and move over your SDK into it. This is how I resolved it.

The only error I was eventually able to get from Android Studio was if i tried to run a test I'd see
NoSuchMethodError: com.android.builder.model.AndroidArtifact.getOutputs()Ljava/util/Collection;: com.android.builder.model.AndroidArtifact.getOutputs()Ljava/util/Collection;

there has been some other posts referring to this issue. Just make sure you do a clean install and don't crap over your older version.

Comment: restart db? unplug your phone and do again. After a bit you will see a red message with something like "I/O Connection refused" right?

Comment: try to kill the adb daemon (using the host process manager) and retry

Comment: i killed the adb process and tried again and no i don't see that message. i'm on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

[This issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72582) on the AOSP bug tracker tells you what is going on. A quick fix is getting rid of `builder-model-0.11.0.jar` from `plugins/android/lib`﻿ in your Android Studio folder. A [patch](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/99790/) has already been submitted and this probably won't happen again with the next update.

Comment: Worth noting: I had to restart Android Studio after removing the jar.